# How to perform ECKA and have an ECPoint returned?

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, smartcard, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I'm using Bouncy Castle to perform the Elliptic Curve Key Aggreement using the ECDH protocol in a smart card related software, as defined in the [BSI-TR-03111](https://www.bsi.bund.de/cae/servlet/contentblob/471398/publicationFile/30615/BSI-TR-03111_pdf.pdf) specs, §3.4 with

The purpose is to perform the Generic Mapping of the nonce in the PACE protocol, as defined in the [ICAO SAC](http://www.icao.int/Security/mrtd/Downloads/Technical%20Reports/NEW%20TRs%20post%20TAG%2022/TR%20-%20Supplemental%20Access%20Control%20V1.1.pdf) Technical Report, §3.4.2.1.1

(I'm using Java but the language is not essential to the matter I guess)

The `KeyAgreement` class makes it very simple (as exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285073/bouncycastle-ecdh-key-agreement-fails)) but it only allows to output the X coordinate of the generated `ECPoint`, that is Z<sub>AB</sub> (which is often, but not always what required.)

Is there any way to have the actual `ECPoint` (that is S<sub>AB</sub>) returned without having to reimplement the algorithm? Even tho' the formula in itself is simple, one must check for errors and anomalies and account for variations (e.g. cofactor multiplication)

Comment: The short answer is no I guess. As a general rule, the provider implements "top-level" algorithms, whereas ECKA-DH is more of a building block algorithm. The building blocks are usually accessible if you are willing to use the lightweight (on-JCE) API directly. It's probably better to mention what high-level algorithm you are trying to implement. In some cases, e.g. ECIES, the provider does have at least the option to use an uncompressed point encoding in the agreement output. Alternatively you may be wanting to use a scheme that is not yet in the provider; then let's look at adding it!

Comment: The purpose is to perform the Generic Mapping of the nonce in the PACE protocol, as defined in the [ICAO SAC](http://www.icao.int/Security/mrtd/Downloads/Technical%20Reports/NEW%20TRs%20post%20TAG%2022/TR%20-%20Supplemental%20Access%20Control%20V1.1.pdf) Technical Report, §3.4.2.1.1 which requires a nonce and two points, one well known and one agreed between the two parties.

Comment: OK, so I would say you're not going to be able to do that via the current provider, but will have to use the lightweight API (i.e. the non-JCE code), and as you anticipate, re-implement some algorithms (even the lightweight agreement classes don't return an ECPoint). Let us know at https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java if there's changes we could make to help, or if you would like to contribute any PACE-related algorithms to BC.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm going to redesign the PACE package, then, in order to wrap the lightweight API under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

I completely forgot about this question. This was the solution I implemented:

```
package com.arjowiggins.arjonaut.crypto.ec;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BasicAgreement;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;

import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * Created by Salvatore on 22/04/2015.
 */
public class ECDHPointAgreement implements BasicAgreement {

    private ECPrivateKeyParameters key;

    public void init(CipherParameters key) {
        this.key = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) key;
    }

    public int getFieldSize() {
        return (key.getParameters().getCurve().getFieldSize() + 7) / 8;
    }

    public BigInteger calculateAgreement(CipherParameters pubKey) {
        ECPoint P = calculatePoint(pubKey);
        return P.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger();
    }

    public ECPoint calculatePoint(CipherParameters pubKey) {
        ECPublicKeyParameters pub = (ECPublicKeyParameters) pubKey;
        ECPoint P = pub.getQ().multiply(key.getD()).normalize();

        if (P.isInfinity()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Infinity is not a valid agreement value for ECDH");
        }
        return P;
    }

}
```

Most of the code comes from BouncyCastle's `KeyAgreement` class.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the curve equation for Y is exactly what I did.

```
public static BigInteger computeAffineY(BigInteger affineX, ECParameterSpec params) {
    ECCurve bcCurve = toBouncyCastleECCurve(params);
    ECFieldElement a = bcCurve.getA();
    ECFieldElement b = bcCurve.getB();
    ECFieldElement x = bcCurve.fromBigInteger(affineX);     
    ECFieldElement y = x.multiply(x).add(a).multiply(x).add(b).sqrt();
    return y.toBigInteger();
}
```